# Hiding action bar on scroll leaves blank space

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-actionbar

I hide the action bar on scroll using the below code but it leaves blank space on the top. I went through some other posts as well but it did not help

I am using Xamarin

My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

recyclerview setup

```
_recyclerView = _view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.videoRecyclerView);
_recyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(new ScrollListner(Activity, _recyclerView));
```

and the scroll listner
    public virtual void OnMoved(int distance)
        {
            _toolbarContainer.TranslationY = -distance;
        }

```
    public virtual void OnShow()
    {
        _toolbarContainer.Animate().TranslationY(0).SetInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).Start();
    }

    public virtual void OnHide()
    {
        _toolbarContainer.Animate().TranslationY(-_toolbarHeight).SetInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).Start();
    }

    public override void OnScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
    {
        base.OnScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.ScrollStateIdle)
        {
            if (_totalScrolledDistance < _toolbarHeight)
            {
                SetVisible();
            }
            else
            {
                if (_controlsVisible)
                {
                    if (_toolbarOffset > HideThreshold)
                    {
                        SetInvisible();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetVisible();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((_toolbarHeight - _toolbarOffset) > ShowThreshold)
                    {
                        SetVisible();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetInvisible();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        base.OnScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        ClipToolbarOffset();
        OnMoved(_toolbarOffset);

        if ((_toolbarOffset < _toolbarHeight && dy > 0) || (_toolbarOffset > 0 && dy < 0))
        {
            _toolbarOffset += dy;
        }

        if (_totalScrolledDistance < 0)
        {
            _totalScrolledDistance = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _totalScrolledDistance += dy;
        }
    }

    private void ClipToolbarOffset()
    {
        if (_toolbarOffset > _toolbarHeight)
        {
            _toolbarOffset = _toolbarHeight;
        }
        else if (_toolbarOffset < 0)
        {
            _toolbarOffset = 0;
        }
    }

    private void SetVisible()
    {
        if (_toolbarOffset > 0)
        {
            OnShow();
            _toolbarOffset = 0;
        }

        _controlsVisible = true;
    }

    private void SetInvisible()
    {
        if (_toolbarOffset < _toolbarHeight)
        {
            OnHide();
            _toolbarOffset = _toolbarHeight;
        }

        _controlsVisible = false;
    }
```

I have now spent more than 4 hours on this tried many things but it does not work at all.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Android Design Support provides `CoordinatorLayout`, a layout which provides an additional level of control over touch events between child views, something which many of the components in the Design library take advantage of. You should check on the Xamarin's website https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign

Comment: @PawanVimukthi where do you suggest I use CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: You should use `CoordinatorLayout` on your activity layout. `CoordinatorLayout` is an parent view, so that you can use child views in it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments you should use

**Coordinator Layout** in combination with your **Toolbar** and set scrollflags on your toolbar as following:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

You can find very good example of it in here:

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

More on the Coordinator Layout:

http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

It's gonna be much cleaner rather than doing this all by yourself manually.